# Pagination showing same posts despite changing page

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I have taken the following pagination code from a 'premium' Wordpress theme to try and integrate this in to a custom one, but can't seem to get it to work:

In the blog.php page template, I have the loop:

```
                $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                $args=array(
                        'paged' => $paged,
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'posts_per_page' => '1',
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'orderby' => 'date',
                );
                 $wp_query = new WP_query($args);
                 if ( $wp_query -> have_posts() ) :
                 $j = 1;
                 while ($wp_query -> have_posts()): $wp_query -> the_post();?>
                 CONTENT HERE
                 <?php endwhile;prestigo_SPaginate();endif;?>
```

And the function for this is:

```
if(!function_exists('prestigo_SPaginate')){
        function prestigo_SPaginate()
        {
            $currentPage = null;
            $totalPage = null;
            global $wp_query;           
                $currentPage = intval(get_query_var('paged'));
            if(empty($currentPage))
            {
                $currentPage = 1;
            }        
            $totalPage = intval(ceil($wp_query->found_posts / intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'))));
            if($totalPage <= 1)
            {
                return '';
            }
            $paginateResult = '<!-- PAGINATION -->
                            <ul class="pagination clearfix">';

            if ($currentPage > 1)
            {
                $paginateResult .= '<li class="pull-left"><a href="'.get_pagenum_link($currentPage - 1).'"><i class="fe arrow_carrot-left"></i></a></li>';
            }elseif ($currentPage = 1)
            {
                $paginateResult .= '<li class="pull-left"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fe arrow_carrot-left"></i></a></li>';
            }
            $paginateResult .= prestigo_ListLink(1, $totalPage, $currentPage);
            if ($currentPage < $totalPage)
            {
                $paginateResult .= "<li class='pull-right'><a href='" . get_pagenum_link($currentPage + 1) . "' class='spaginate-next'><i class='fe arrow_carrot-right'></i></a></li>";
            }elseif($currentPage = $totalPage){
                $paginateResult .= "<li class='pull-right'><span class='spaginate-next'><i class='fe arrow_carrot-right'></i></span></li>";
            }
            $paginateResult .= "</ul><!-- //PAGINATION -->";
            echo $paginateResult;
            return $paginateResult;
        }
    }

    if(!function_exists('prestigo_ListLink')){
        function prestigo_ListLink($intStart, $totalPage, $currentPage)
        {
            $pageHidden = '<span class="spaginate-hidden">... </span>';
            $linkResult = "";
            $hiddenBefore = false;
            $hiddenAfter = false;
            for ($i = $intStart; $i <= $totalPage; $i++)
            {
                if($currentPage === intval($i))
                {
                    $linkResult .= '<li class="active"><a href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                }
                else if(($i <= 6 && $currentPage < 10) || $i == $totalPage || $i == 1 || $i < 4 || ($i <= 6 && $totalPage <= 6) || ($i > $currentPage && ($i <= ($currentPage + 2))) || ($i < $currentPage && ($i >= ($currentPage - 2))) || ($i >= ($totalPage - 2) && $i < $totalPage))
                {
                    $linkResult .= '<li><a href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                    if($i <= 6 && $currentPage < 10)
                    {
                        $hiddenBefore = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!$hiddenBefore)
                    {
                        $linkResult .= $pageHidden;
                        $hiddenBefore = true;
                    }
                    else if(!$hiddenAfter && $i > $currentPage)
                    {
                        $linkResult .= $pageHidden;
                        $hiddenAfter = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return $linkResult;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately the pagination displays but clicking on page number 2 shows the same posts as page number 1.

Any advice would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pagination these days I use the following:

```
function wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav() {

if( is_singular() )
    return;

global $wp_query;

/** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
    return;

$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

/** Add current page to the array */
if ( $paged >= 1 )
    $links[] = $paged;

/** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
    $links[] = $paged - 1;
    $links[] = $paged - 2;
}

if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
    $links[] = $paged + 2;
    $links[] = $paged + 1;
}

echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";

/** Previous Post Link */
if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

/** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
    $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

    if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
        echo '<li>…</li>';
}

/** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
sort( $links );
foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
    $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
}

/** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
        echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

    $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
}

/** Next Post Link */
if ( get_next_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 3):

After struggling for hours on this (and 6 years after the question was asked), for me the solution was lying within the $paged parameter:

I changed

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

to

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
      $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
      $paged = get_query_var('page');
    } else {
      $paged = 1;
    }
```

And then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

try changing the `paged` parameter and query var; I've experienced in the past the variable being different than what the Codex says. try switching `paged` with `page` in both the `get_query_var` and the `WP_Query` args.